# how to transform R dataframe to rows of indicator values

Tags: python, r, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
A 2
B 4
C 3
```

and I would like to make a data frame with the following

```
A 0
A 1
B 0
B 0
B 0
B 1
C 0
C 0
C 1.
```

So for B, I want to make 4 rows and each one is 0 except for the last one which is 1. Similarly, for A, I'll have 2 rows and the first one has a 0 and the second one has a 1.

In general, if I have a row in the original table with `X n`, I want to return n rows in the new table with n-1 of them being `X 0` and the final one as `X 1`.

Is there a way to do this in R? Or Python or SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `R`, we may use `uncount` to replicate the rows from the second column and replace the second column with binary by converting the first to logical column (`duplicated`)

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
 uncount(v2) %>%
 mutate(v2 = +(!duplicated(v1, fromLast = TRUE)))
```

-output

```
 v1 v2
1  A  0
2  A  1
3  B  0
4  B  0
5  B  0
6  B  1
7  C  0
8  C  0
9  C  1
```

---

Or in `Python`

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"v1":["A", "B", "C"], "v2": [2, 4, 3]})
df2 = df1.reindex(df1.index.repeat(df1.v2))
df2['v2'] = (~df2.duplicated(subset = ['v2'], keep = "last")) + 0
df2
   v1   v2
0   A   0
0   A   1
1   B   0
1   B   0
1   B   0
1   B   1
2   C   0
2   C   0
2   C   1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c("A", "B", "C"), v2 = c(2L, 4L, 3L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not that hard with base R...

```r
d <- data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:3], n = c(2L, 4L, 3L))
d
##   x n
## 1 A 2
## 2 B 4
## 3 C 3

data.frame(x = rep.int(d$x, d$n), i = replace(integer(sum(d$n)), cumsum(d$n), 1L))
##   x i
## 1 A 0
## 2 A 1
## 3 B 0
## 4 B 0
## 5 B 0
## 6 B 1
## 7 C 0
## 8 C 0
## 9 C 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# load package
library(data.table)

# set as data table
setDT(df)

# work
df1 <- df[rep(seq(.N), b), ][, c := 1:.N, a]

df1[, d := 0][b == c, d := 1][, b := d][, c('c', 'd') := NULL]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way in python to replicate what @akrun did in `R`:

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, tibble, uncount, mutate, duplicated, as_integer
>>> df1 = tibble(v1=list("ABC"), v2=[2, 4, 3])
>>> df1 >> uncount(f.v2) >> mutate(
...   v2=as_integer(~duplicated(f.v1, from_last=True))
... )
        v1       v2
  <object> <object>
0        A        0
1        A        1
2        B        0
3        B        0
4        B        0
5        B        1
6        C        0
7        C        0
8        C        1
```

I am the author of [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar), which is backed by pandas.